# How can I change the specefic event background color in JQuery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How can I change the event background color while on rendering events on calendar. How can I change specific event background color in javascript, I have assigned the event with id.

Answer (score 1):

you may alter the "`fc-event`" values in the `fullcalendar.css` to change the default event background,

or you can add a new css class as follows:

```
.newtype,
.fc-agenda .newtype.fc-event-time,
.newtype a {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #6da;    /* default BORDER color (probably the same as background-color) */
    background-color: #6da; /* #36c; default BACKGROUND color */
    color: #fff;            /* default TEXT color */
}
```

and specify it to the event throught `className`:

```
event.className="newtype";
```

p.s. you need get the event object by function `.fullCalendar( 'clientEvents', event_id)` first

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

would make sure the event has a specific "className" and then color it through css. more info here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/Colors/